# Android DirectionalViewPager and widget

Tags: android, widget, android-viewpager, appwidgetprovider

How can I use Android-DirectionalViewPager when I create a widget? When I switch extends FragmentActivity to extends AppWidgetProvider I get a message:

The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type SampleActivity

I would like to make a horizontal scrolling.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/
how use this in android widget?